# Entity Framework - More control over child entity resolution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I'm having problems getting the **Include** expression to do what I need.

Say I have these classes:

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}

public class Post 
{ 
    public int PostId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Then if I call

```
context.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)
```

That all works as expected. The Posts collection is populated. However, I have a scenario where I don't want to retrieve all posts. I want to retrieve **one** particular post based on another complex query. e.g. change Blog to...

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Post MostPopularPost { get; set; } 
}
```

I want MostPopularPost to be the FirstOrDefault entity in the Posts table once a certain condition/ordering/grouping has been applied. In my real scenario, the child entity depends on configuration, security etc. - i.e. you may get a different entity depending on who you are or how the system's configured. The resolution of MostPopularPost depends on additional criteria - not just foreign key relationships. How do I get Entity Framework to do the property "fix-up" from the result of a more complex query?

An additional constraint is that my method needs to return an IQueryable as the expression is passed back to the application to add further criteria. Therefore ToList() and other in-memory processing isn't really going to work. Ideally it all needs to be executed in the database.

Comment: *- not just foreign key relationships* Well, EF handles only foreign key relationships. So no automatic behavior. Define DTO and use projection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a query returning a custom object

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb738694(v=vs.100).aspx

In your case, I think you want to make a partial class in the same project but separate file from Blog that includes your method.  The partial class file will be class name Blog.